# Authentication for json?

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, authentication

What are the various ways to autenticate a json page? this is to prevent others from looking at the response data? I'm using asp.net for the output of json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as for any other kind of page, really. HTTP basic, HTTP digest, cookie session ID, explicit session ID parameter, username+password parameters on every request.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm a fan of dead simple basic auth with my json requests - its easy to set up and fairly secure.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication which would be controlled by something like http://username:password@myawesomesite.com/json_request.json

Beyond that there's a lot you can do to complicate the issue with handshakes and oauth.  JSON is really just the end result data - how that data is requested is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The question you have asked is wrongly asked. You want to authenticate a Json page , it should have been "autheticate a json based request" or encrypt your json based response.

Is that what you are trying to say?